# Dataset shuffled with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

I use the `image_dataset_from_directory()` function from keras to create an images dataset.

```
ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    seed=42,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    label_mode='binary'
)
```

I set a fixed seed, so, if I execute this function several times, the dataset is shuffled the same way.
Meanwhile, when I try to predict my model output for this dataset (`print(model.predict(ds))`),
the output is always different.
It seems like the dataset is shuffled again because when I print the images in this way :

```
for x, y in ds:
    print(x)
```

the output is also different.

What don't I understand ?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory)? There is a default arg `shuffle=True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `image_dataset_from_directory` uses the `tf.data.Dataset` API. The default behaviour of `tf.data.Dataset.shuffle`, is to reshuffle the dataset at each iteration. From the [documentation of `shuffle`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle):

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(3)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(3, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
# [1, 0, 2]
list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
# [1, 2, 0]
```

If you want to shuffle your dataset, but have the same exact order at each iteration over the dataset, you will need to shuffle the dataset after creating it and specify `reshuffle_each_iteration=False`.

```
ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    seed=42,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    label_mode='binary',
    shuffle=False
)
# default buffer in image_dataset_from_directory is 8*batch_size
ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=8*batch_size, seed=42, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
```

Regarding the seed, it makes the dataset being shuffled predictably **at each execution of the program**, not at each iteration through the dataset. You can read more about seeds and tensorflow's random behaviour in the [documentation of `tf.random.set_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed).

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer, that's what I thought, actually. Meanwhile, I have difficulties to understand the interest of such a behaviour. Why is it usefull ?

Comment: You can read this: [Why should the data be shuffled for machine learning tasks](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24511/why-should-the-data-be-shuffled-for-machine-learning-tasks)